# How to access record from sessionStorage by id/key?

Tags: javascript, json, sessionstorage

I have data that is saved in sessionStorage and here is example of how I save data in sessionStorage.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Components/Functions.cfc?method='+cfMethod,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
    sessionStorage.setItem('Books',JSON.stringify(obj.DATA));
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('Error: '+errorThrown);
});
```

Once records are saved in sessionStorage they look like this:

```
{
  "14": {
    "COMMENTS": "",
    "RECORDID": 14,
    "NAME": "Decorah Sector",
    "AGENCY": "01",
    "CODE": "011A"
  },
  "15": {
    "COMMENTS": "",
    "RECORDID": 15,
    "NAME": "Waukon Field",
    "AGENCY": "01",
    "CODE": "011B"
  },
  "16": {
    "COMMENTS": "Test 524",
    "RECORDID": 16,
    "NAME": "New Hampton",
    "AGENCY": "01",
    "CODE": "011C"
  }
}
```

As you can see each record has unique key, once user decide to edit record all I have to do is pull data from sessionStorage and pass `id` that is matching unique key. Here is example of my edit function:

```
function editBook() {
    var recordID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), // This id will be retrieved from presentation table. Each row has unique id that match sessonStorage.Books records.
        bookRecord = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.Books[recordID]);
        console.log(bookRecord); //For testing purpose.
    if(bookRecord){
        $.each(regionRecord, function(name, value){
            var elementName = $('[name="'+'frmSave_'+name.toLowerCase()+'"]'),
                elementType = elementName.prop('type'),
                elementVal = $.trim(value);

            switch(elementType){
                case 'select-one':
                    elementName.val(elementVal);
                    break;
                case 'textarea':
                    elementName.val(elementVal);
                    break;
                default:
                    elementName.val(elementVal);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For some reason after I `console.log()` bookRecord I'm not getting data for specific `id` that I passed in sessionStorage. I'm not sure if my syntax is correct or something else might be the problem. I'm following the same steps as JS object is using to access records based on unique key. If anyone see where is the problem in my code please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure you mean [tag:jsobject] and not just JSON (hover the tag in the question)?

Comment: I have tried saving obj.DATA in javascript object like `var books = {};` and I was able to access record like this `books[recordID]` that will retrieve specific row/set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is the result of `JSON.parse()`, you need to put the indexing there.

```
bookRecord = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.Books)[recordID];
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. Is there a way to insert/update record in sessionStorage object? Same that I'm doing to pull the record by key but this time I want to insert/update.

Comment: Assign the result of `JSON.parse()` to a variable, update that object, then store `JSON.stringify(thatVariable)` in session storage.

Comment: Since that's the case and I guess only way to update/insert records in session storage, is there any advantage of using sessionStorage instead of JS objects?

Comment: The purpose of sessionStorage is to hold the value of the variable when you switch between pages or reload the page.

Comment: I use this more to save some hits to the server. So when user first search for records I save them in storage. Then when I need to/edit that data I pull record from the storage. I'm debating should I go with JS object or sessionStorage.

Comment: That's a false dichotomy. It's always objects, the only question is whether you save the objects in localStorage so they persist between pages without having to query the server.

Comment: I maybe used the wrong words, yes I always use objects but question is do I store them as global variable in my js file or in local/session storage. I was thinking about sessionStorage because I have single page app and I do not see why this data should stay in the browser once session ends.

Comment: You don't need to do anything for a SPA. Global variables stay set as long as the user stays on the page.

Comment: I guess that is the answer to my questions. I was on the right track with global variables. Thank you for your time to explain differences.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
bookRecord = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.Books[recordID]);
```

should be

```
bookRecord = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.Books)[recordID];
```

because you want to access the record of the object which you have parsed from JSON.

Comment: Is there a way to update/insert new/existing record in sessionStorage?

Comment: @espresso_coffee Same way you assign any object value, you just set the key = an existing key.